# Cloned html row disappear after postback

Tags: jquery, html

Please give a solution.
On click of button i clone html row with textbox.it is cloning successfully but when i click on submit then cloned row disappears. i want to keep it.below is my jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var count = 0; var acount = 0;
        $('#add-button').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            count++;
            var template = $('.chiller-record').clone();
            template.attr('id', 'VI' + count);
            template.find('input[type=text]').val('');
            template.find('input[type=hidden]').val(count);
            $.each(template.find('input[type=text]'), function () {
                var name = $(this).attr('name');
                name = name.replace('0', count);
                $(this).attr('name', name);
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                id = id.replace('0', count);
                $(this).attr('id', id);

            });
            template.removeClass('chiller-record').addClass('chiller-record1');
            $('.list-chiller-record').append(template);
            var col = document.createElement('td');
            $('.list-chiller-record tr:last').append(col);
            col.innerHTML = "<a class='btn btn-white btn-danger btn-bold removeLink' id='removeLink'><i class='ace-icon fa fa-trash-o'></i> Remove</a>";
        });
        })
    });
```

Comment: This is by design. DOM changes do not persist over requests automatically. You need to store the state of the page somewhere (cookie, session, localStorage, server storage...) and then load that state again when you next load the page.

Comment: Thank you rory for your reply.can u give me some example of how to store it via jquery.